# Publish google analytics report in real time

Tags: php, google-analytics

Hi is there any way to put into our web-sites an iframe, or something that show us a miny report of our site in real time?

Comment: _All things are possible to him who believeth (in good questions)._ -- First Book of SO, Chapter 3, Verse 1

Comment: check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com  It uses iFrame and you don't have to know the API at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Analytics Reporting API

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataGettingStarted.html

Answer (score 4):

Google Analytics data is constantly collected but you will notice via usage that [Google doesn't process all data in real-time](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=66b00c4cf7eb7970&hl=en) so it may not help you achieve your objective. Instead, I would recommend something like [Piwik](http://piwik.org) that does report in real-time.

Piwik is also open source with an API that will allow you to develop either a plug-in or integrate it into your own app.

Note that Piwik is not hosted as Google Analytics is, you install Piwik on your own hosting environment and this is a big difference to some people.

I hope that this helps you!

Comment: I have both set up on 2 sites by request of the owners and there is a definite difference on when data is available in the application with Piwik always available first so I don't doubt it. Google Analytics is the more popular option as first it's by Google and secondly it is what people are used to, but my experience tells me that Google isn't real-time and Piwik is so if real-time is important I would recommend to give Piwik a try.

Comment: i have installed piwik into my site..
What must i do to publish statistics of my site?
I don't search piwik page enought
**It seems to be very good!**

Comment: The question says especcially for google analytics report..
Sorry

Comment: I understand you specified Google Analytics, as I said earlier, Google doesn't support what you're looking for, real-time. By answering as per the specified Google Analytics I would be doing you and anyone else reading a disservice, but by giving an answer that will solve your problems the answer doesn't get approved because you specified Google Analytics, you now have a tool that does solve your problems, I have still provided more help on it despite you already accepting another answer and my answer still isn't accepted even though it sounds like  it is the right solution for your problem

Answer (score 2):

[Megalytic](http://megalytic.com) enables you to embed a mini analytics report in your site or blog.  Here's a demo: http://blog.megalytic.com/embedded-client-pages.  More details [here](http://blog.megalytic.com/client-accounts-support).  Handles Google Analytics, Facebook, and Twitter.

Comment: The links you provided seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

For publishing Google Analytics report real time, Google has launched new API. Its Google Real Time API for Google Analytics.

With this you can perform real time website dashboard. To get start development check it https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/devguide

This is very similar to Google Analytics, with this you can extract data which are available in the form of [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/) at Google Analytics account.